# How to return JSON (or even text) using iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I've been trying to call an API using node.js. The setup is I have a website under IIS where in the main page, a fetch call is made to a js (test.js) file in a folder which is configured to be handled by iisnode (indicated by a web.config). This is the fetch call:

```
fetch("http://localhost/node/node_sdk/test.js")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => {
      console.log(res);     
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is the code inside test.js:

```
return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 61844,
        path: '/api/employees',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    const request = http.request(options, (response) => {
    
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
          throw error;
      });
    });

    request.end();
}));
```

When the page is loaded and the fetch API called, the REST API is triggered (confirmed via a breakpoint), my problem is I can't get anything returned except an error message. It returns:

```
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly
```

But when I change the code above to something simple like:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I can get the return value from this code which makes me think it doesn't have to do anything with the error message above (web.config not found). I've tried the event tracing bat file inside iisnode, I got something like node being terminated before process can finish but only on the first example, not in the createServer one.

My questions are:

1. Can I return json or text from a Fetch call on a js file handled by iisnode without creating a server (http.createServer)?
2. If not, lets say I really need to use createServer, is it fine that every time the page loads, http.createServer gets called?

Comment: It seems you create the sample project in `C:` drive. So you get no permission message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you elaborate a bit? But the site is not directly in C: drive

Comment: You can try to delpoy your webapp in `E:/` or `D:/`, if the problem is solved, it means that it is a permission problem. Then I will explain to you.